# Split divs/buttons dynamically into columns based on max height? (Possible with flex or css only in BS4)?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have a page that makes an ajax call that will return a date and N number of times.

These are rendered as a UL for each day, with the first li being the day, and subsequent li indicating times, but i could easily wrap them in div's if needed.

I have a wrapper div that is locked to 300px in height. Easier to explain with images, so how it currently renders, and how i would like it to render is below. I'm trying to get it to wrap to the right to stay within the 300px allotment, given i can get an unknown number of items returned.

I'm using bootstrap 4, and wondering if this can just be done in CSS without using any JS to manipulate the DOM?

Instead of overflowing outside of the parent container, is it possible to have it wrap within the container?

```
<div class="slots">
    <ul class="slotlist">
        <li>
            <button class="day" value="2020-01-29">Wed, Jan 29</button>
         </li>
         <li>
            <button value="1" data-group="2020-01-29" class="slot">
            <span class=""><i><span></span></i>1:20 PM</span>
            </button>
         </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The outer container is set as follows:

```
   .slots {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
```

Simply, the red box is the size of the parent div (around 300px in height, and 100% in width)

[image: Overflowing the div]

Now, how i'd like it look (i realize i offset the times in the 2nd column, not required)

[image: How i'd like it to look]

Answer (score 1):

with `flex` and `flex-flow: column wrap` you can do it.

POC:

```css
.container {
  height: 300px;
  border: solid;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  padding: 10px;
  align-content: flex-start;
}

.time {
  height: 30px;
  width: 50px;
  padding: 25px;
  border: solid red;
  margin: 5px
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="time">1:20</div>
  <div class="time">1:21</div>
  <div class="time">1:22</div>
  <div class="time">1:23</div>
  <div class="time">1:24</div>
  <div class="time">1:25</div>
</div>
```